# How I can disable sorting function on vuejs v-table columns?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a v-table and I need remove disable sort function when user click on header.
How I can do It?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set `sortable: false` on the column headers you want to disable.

Answer (score 0):

you can use property disable-sort:

```html
<v-data-table disable-sort>
</v-data-table>
```

Comment: Doesn't work in vuetify 3